Unable to delete directory in react native \reanimated or \build or \arm64-v8a
I am trying to run react native app. However out of nowhere it is giving me an error. I tried to reinstall everything. I tried to delete the folder reanimated but then it just cannot delete another folder. What could be the issue?
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:prepareHeadersForPrefab'.
> Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\SearvApp\frontend\searvice_app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build\prefab-headers\reanimated'

Doctor:
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Versions:
java version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16 LTS
React Native CLI version:14.1.0
Node.js version:v20.17.0
react-native@0.73.8
gradle 8.3
Android 14 34 api

One dependancy issue:
┬ react-redux@8.0.2 invalid: "^7.2.1 || ^8.1.3 || ^9.0.0" from node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit

Paths in systems variables:
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools


I tried to reinstall everything, but nothing helped. So I decided to also upgrade to Windows 10, version 22H2. That somehow solved the issue.
